# Gist shortcode is not working

Tags: shortcode, code, embed

I freshly installed a brand new Wordpress for testing purpose as I am intending to refresh my current website. One of the requirement I have is to be able to embed code from Gist. Following the Wordpress documentation, newer version comes with a specific shortcode for Gist : [Gist Shortcode](http://en.support.wordpress.com/gist/)

The issue is that it does not work at all. I tried pasting simply the url on a single line or wraping it around [gist] tags but nothing works. The url simply displays as raw text inside the post. I do know that some plugins provide the same functionality but I really wish to use the Wordpress builtin functionality.

My site has been automatically hosted and installed on an Azure website, is running PHP 5.4 and Wordpress 3.8.1.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about when you ad the embed code from Github Gists in the text editor on its own line?

Comment: One possibility is to use `wp_embed_register_handler` to transform a gist link into the corresponding gist script. But maybe you are only seeking a shortcode?

Comment: @BradDalton: At first I tried to just add the script from Gist and it did not work. But then I realized it just did not worked on preview mode. I did worked when I published. This is indeed a pretty good solution. Thanks!

Comment: @birgire: Actually I am not seeking any particular form of synthax. I just seek for simplicity. In the past I used SynthaxHighlighter and really, even with plugins it is realy pain to maintain and update code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gist tags and oembed handling is specific to WordPress.com, and doesn't come bundled with standard WordPress from wordpress.org

You will need to acquire a plugin to register gists as an oembed provider, or add embed tags.

There are plenty of plugins that do this available, [I use this one](https://github.com/inpsyde/Inpsyde-oEmbed-Gist). If you'd like to write your own, you'll want to use the `wp_embed_register_handler` function as a starting point.

Comment: Indeed I was not aware that this documentation was purely reserved for the wordpress.com hosted sites. Thanks for the clarification, I'll go for a plugin then.